# How to delete duplicate values in a list?

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Let us consider the list:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'z', 'z']
```

I want to delete these duplicate values list-x and want the result as:

```
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z']
```

Comment: Does the order of elements matter?

Comment: They answered this here. With or without preserving the order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order

Comment: Does the 'z' or 'p' make that much difference, does it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If ordering doesn't matter, use a set:

```
>>> list(set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'p', 'p']))
['a', 'p', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```

If ordering *does* matter, use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict 
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'p', 'p']).keys()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'p']
```

Comment: +1, Just a remarque no need for passing 0 to ``OrderedDict.fromkeys`` just ``OrderedDict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'p', 'p']).keys()``

Comment: +1 for a neat solution that preserves order easily

Answer (score 4):

Since nothing was stated about preserving order, this approach will work:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'z', 'z']

list(set(x))
```

will give you

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'z']
```

By changing your list to a `set` you eliminate all duplicates. You apply `list()` to change your non-duplicate data back to a list.

Comment: The result is not in the same order !

Comment: @mouad Nothing about order was stated in the post, just eliminating duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
y=[ x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if not x[i] in x[:i]]
```

I think that this would be the simplest solution possible.

Comment: This one is O(n²), and it isn't even simpler.

Comment: Well, I didn't say that it was the fastest, but it is a one-liner...

Comment: @hfhc2: So is the OrderedDict solution..