# How to remove duplicate values from a beautiful soup result set whilst preserving order?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, duplicates

I have a scenario where I am searching through values in a beautiful soup result set and treating them differently depending on their contents, eg:

```
for i in bs_result_set:
    if 'this unique string' in i.text:
        print 'aaaa'
    else:
        print 'bbbb'
```

However I have realised that the unique condition actually occurs twice in the result set however I do not need that second replicate value and therefore want to remove it from the result set in the first place.

I have tried approaches to removing duplicate values in a `list` (whilst preserving order) but these do not seem to work on an object that is a beautiful soup result set.  Eg i used logic from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11541660) to try:

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
OrderedDict.fromkeys(bs_result_set).keys()
```

But that didn't seem to remove the duplicate values.

So my question is how do i remove duplicate values from a beautiful soup result set whilst preserving order?

Comment: What defines a duplicate though? Are the attribute values equal? Or just the attribute names? Should the textual content match exactly or just both have the same substring? What about nested elements?

Comment: good questions, the values are exact duplicates, they are both a div containing lots of text, html tags and comments.

Comment: It is interesting then that the `OrderedDict.fromkeys()` trick does not work for you; BS4 `Tag` elements define equality just like that; same name, same attributes (names and values) and same contents (tested recursively). Can you test if `elemA == elemB` is `True` for the elements that you think are duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
h = {}
for i in bs_result_set:
    if i not in h:
        if 'this unique string' in i.text:
            print 'aaaa'
        else:
            print 'bbbb'
        h[i] = 1
```

If the key is not *i* but found from *i* (computed, field, etc.), you can do

```
h = {}
for i in bs_result_set:
    key = <some formula involving i>
    if key not in h:
        if 'this unique string' in i.text:
            print 'aaaa'
        else:
            print 'bbbb'
        h[key] = 1
```

Comment: what does `h[i] = 1` do? is that somehow saying `i` in `h` is limited to one occurrence only?

Comment: *h[i] = 1* simply adds *i* to the hash table *h* (actually, you can do the same with a set).